# Breadth- and Depth- First Search in C#

Tags: c#, breadth-first-search, depth-first-search

Another recreational implementation for review! As a side comment, for some reason I just feel like `if (visited.Contains(vertex)) { .. }` isn't necessary, as this example doesn't break from not including it in either algorithm. Any feedback is welcome!

**Graph.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CodeReview
{
    public class Graph<T>
    {
        public Dictionary<T, HashSet<T>> AdjacencyList { get; } = new Dictionary<T, HashSet<T>>();

        public Graph() { }

        public Graph(IEnumerable<T> vertices, IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>> edges)
        {
            foreach (var vertex in vertices)
            {
                AddVertex(vertex);
            }

            foreach (var edge in edges)
            {
                AddEdge(edge);
            }
        }

        public void AddVertex(T vertex)
        {
            AdjacencyList[vertex] = new HashSet<T>();
        }

        public void AddEdge(Tuple<T, T> edge)
        {
            if (AdjacencyList.ContainsKey(edge.Item1) && AdjacencyList.ContainsKey(edge.Item2))
            {
                AdjacencyList[edge.Item1].Add(edge.Item2);
                AdjacencyList[edge.Item2].Add(edge.Item1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CodeReview
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var vertices = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
            var edges = new[] {
                Tuple.Create(1, 2),
                Tuple.Create(1, 3),
                Tuple.Create(2, 4),
                Tuple.Create(3, 5),
                Tuple.Create(3, 6),
                Tuple.Create(4, 7),
                Tuple.Create(5, 7),
                Tuple.Create(5, 8),
                Tuple.Create(5, 6),
                Tuple.Create(8, 9),
                Tuple.Create(9, 10)
            };

            var graph = new Graph<int>(vertices, edges);

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", BFS(graph, 1)));
            // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", DFS(graph, 1)));
            // 1, 3, 6, 5, 8, 9, 10, 7, 4, 2

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        // using HashSet for O(1) access and loop operations
        public static HashSet<T> BFS<T>(Graph<T> graph, T start)
        {
            var visited = new HashSet<T>();

            if (!graph.AdjacencyList.ContainsKey(start))
            {
                return visited;
            }

            var queue = new Queue<T>();
            queue.Enqueue(start);

            while (queue.Count > 0)
            {
                var vertex = queue.Dequeue();

                if (visited.Contains(vertex))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                visited.Add(vertex);

                foreach (var neighbor in graph.AdjacencyList[vertex])
                {
                    if (!visited.Contains(neighbor))
                    {
                        queue.Enqueue(neighbor);
                    }
                }
            }

            return visited;
        }

        // using HashSet for O(1) access and loop operations
        public static HashSet<T> DFS<T>(Graph<T> graph, T start)
        {
            var visited = new HashSet<T>();

            if (!graph.AdjacencyList.ContainsKey(start))
            {
                return visited;
            }

            var stack = new Stack<T>();
            stack.Push(start);

            while (stack.Count > 0)
            {
                var vertex = stack.Pop();

                if (visited.Contains(vertex))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                visited.Add(vertex);

                foreach (var neighbor in graph.AdjacencyList[vertex])
                {
                    if (!visited.Contains(neighbor))
                    {
                        stack.Push(neighbor);
                    }
                }
            }

            return visited;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I think the static search methods should not be static but rather methods in the Graph class. Both methods look very similar, other than the fact that one uses a Queue and the other a Stack. In the interest of being DRY this can be modified using an interface.

I also find it needless to pass in the vertices along with edges.  By virtue of passing in an edge, you know your vertices.

Since `AdjacencyList` is public, I suggest making it an `IDictionary`.

An interface for a searcher is simple:

```
interface IEdgeSearcher<T>
{
    void Add(T item);
    int Count { get; }
    T GetNext();
}
```

The 2 different search classes implementing the interface could be private to `Graph`:

```
private class SearchQueue<TSearch> : IEdgeSearcher<TSearch>
{
    private Queue<TSearch> _queue;
    private SearchQueue() { _queue = new Queue<TSearch>(); }
    public static SearchQueue<T> Create() => new SearchQueue<T>();
    public void Add(TSearch item) { _queue.Enqueue(item); }
    public int Count => _queue.Count;
    public TSearch GetNext() => _queue.Dequeue();
}

private class SearchStack<TSearch> : IEdgeSearcher<TSearch>
{
    private Stack<TSearch> _stack;
    private SearchStack() { _stack = new Stack<TSearch>(); }
    public static SearchStack<TSearch> Create() => new SearchStack<TSearch>();
    public void Add(TSearch item) { _stack.Push(item); }
    public int Count => _stack.Count;
    public TSearch GetNext() => _stack.Pop();
}
```

Back in `Graph` you would call a respective searcher with one line:

```
public HashSet<T> BreadthFirstSearch(T start) => Search(SearchQueue<T>.Create(), start);
public HashSet<T> DepthFirstSearch(T start) => Search(SearchStack<T>.Create(), start);
```

Those are public, but call a new private method that expects the interface:

```
private HashSet<T> Search(IEdgeSearcher<T> searcher, T start)
{
    var visited = new HashSet<T>();

    if (!AdjacencyList.ContainsKey(start))
    {
        return visited;
    }

    searcher.Add(start);

    while (searcher.Count > 0)
    {
        var vertex = searcher.GetNext();

        visited.Add(vertex);

        foreach (var neighbor in AdjacencyList[vertex])
        {
            if (!visited.Contains(neighbor))
            {
                searcher.Add(neighbor);
            }
        }
    }

    return visited;
}
```

Bringing it all together, the modified Graph would look like:

```
public class Graph<T>
{
    public IDictionary<T, HashSet<T>> AdjacencyList { get; } = new Dictionary<T, HashSet<T>>();

    public Graph() { }

    public Graph(IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>> edges)
    {
        foreach (var edge in edges)
        {
            AddEdge(edge);
        }
    }

    public void AddVertex(T vertex)
    {
        AdjacencyList[vertex] = new HashSet<T>();
    }

    public void AddEdge(Tuple<T, T> edge)
    {
        if (!AdjacencyList.ContainsKey(edge.Item1)) { AddVertex(edge.Item1); }
        if (!AdjacencyList.ContainsKey(edge.Item2)) { AddVertex(edge.Item2); }
        if (!AdjacencyList[edge.Item1].Contains(edge.Item2)) { AdjacencyList[edge.Item1].Add(edge.Item2);  }
        if (!AdjacencyList[edge.Item2].Contains(edge.Item1)) { AdjacencyList[edge.Item2].Add(edge.Item1); }
    }

    public HashSet<T> BreadthFirstSearch(T start) => Search(SearchQueue<T>.Create(), start);
    public HashSet<T> DepthFirstSearch(T start) => Search(SearchStack<T>.Create(), start);

    private HashSet<T> Search(IEdgeSearcher<T> searcher, T start)
    {
        var visited = new HashSet<T>();

        if (!AdjacencyList.ContainsKey(start))
        {
            return visited;
        }

        searcher.Add(start);

        while (searcher.Count > 0)
        {
            var vertex = searcher.GetNext();

            visited.Add(vertex);

            foreach (var neighbor in AdjacencyList[vertex])
            {
                if (!visited.Contains(neighbor))
                {
                    searcher.Add(neighbor);
                }
            }
        }

        return visited;
    }

    private class SearchQueue<TSearch> : IEdgeSearcher<TSearch>
    {
        private Queue<TSearch> _queue;
        private SearchQueue() { _queue = new Queue<TSearch>(); }
        public static SearchQueue<T> Create() => new SearchQueue<T>();
        public void Add(TSearch item) { _queue.Enqueue(item); }
        public int Count => _queue.Count;
        public TSearch GetNext() => _queue.Dequeue();
    }

    private class SearchStack<TSearch> : IEdgeSearcher<TSearch>
    {
        private Stack<TSearch> _stack;
        private SearchStack() { _stack = new Stack<TSearch>(); }
        public static SearchStack<TSearch> Create() => new SearchStack<TSearch>();
        public void Add(TSearch item) { _stack.Push(item); }
        public int Count => _stack.Count;
        public TSearch GetNext() => _stack.Pop();
    }
}
```